# List to Json array InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, mysql, json, jpa

I have a util.List with offers. The variables of class offer are:

```
Integer id, Date startDate, Date endDate, String offerMessage, String creationDate, String updateDate.
```

I generated JPA entities and Controller with NetBeans from a MySQL database where i had set startDate, endDate as Timestamp in the db.

As you can see the annotations in the entity are:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "startDate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startDate;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "endDate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date endDate;
```

When i test my axis webservice where i do something like:

in WebService:

```
reply = _protocol.reply(request);
```

and in Protocol:

```
public String reply(String request) throws Exception {
    String reply = "I dont understand you!";
    try {
        if (request.equals("a")) {
            OfferJpaController oferJpaController = new OfferJpaController();
            List<Offer> allOffers = oferJpaController.findOfferEntities();
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeAdapter() ).create();
            reply = gson.toJson(allOffers);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
    }
    return reply;
}
```

I get Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Message: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

As i can imagine, the problem is the util.Date, i searched in other questions here, but i did not managed to solve this. What should i do? Maybe store the Timestamp field as integer in db and make pre-post actions for database conversions?

Answer (score 1):

private static class DateTimeTypeConverter
      implements JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer {

```
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(DateTime src, Type srcType, JsonSerializationContext context) {
  return new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());
}

@Override
public DateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context)
    throws JsonParseException {
  try {
    return new DateTime(json.getAsString());
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // May be it came in formatted as a java.util.Date, so try that
    Date date = context.deserialize(json, Date.class);
    return new DateTime(date);
  }
}
```

}

Comment: and then what should i do?